# Move multiple letters in string using regex

Tags: php, regex, regular-language

Using a regular expression I want to move two letters in a string.

```
W28
L36
W29-L32
```

Should be changed to:

```
28W
36L
29W-32L
```

The numbers vary between `25` and `44`. The letters that need to be moved are always "W" and/or "L" and the "W" is always first when they both exist in the string.
I need to do this with a single regular expression using PHP. Any ideas would be awesome!

**EDIT:**
I'm new to regular expressions and tried a lot of things without success. The closest I came was using `"/\b(W34)\b/"` for each possibility. I also found something about using variables in the replace function but had no luck using these.

Comment: And what did you try? Please post your attempts to help you better.

Comment: I tried a lot of different things but can't get closer than: /\b(W34)\b/ for each possibility but you can image that's not what I want.
Edit:
Why the down votes? I am asking for any ideas... Not the complete solution...

Comment: Please put the regex you tried into the question and explain why it did not work. Then, I and maybe someone else will be able to upvote.

Comment: @DipenShah: Could you please let me know what that `canihasregex` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex `\b(W34)\b` matches exactly `W34` as a whole word. You need a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match `W` or `L`, and some alternatives to match the numeric range, and use the most of [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

You  can use the following regex replacement:

```
$re = '/\b([WL])(2[5-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-4])\b/'; 
$str = "W28\nL36\nW29-L32"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, "$2$1", $str);
echo $result;
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/vv54uc)

Here, `([WL])` matches and captures either `W` or `L` into group 1, and `(2[5-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-4])` matches integer numbers from 25 till 44 and captures into group 2. [Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) are used to reverse the order of the groups in the replacement string.

And here is [a regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eM7mB5/1) in case you want to adjust it later.

Comment: Wauw... that's awesome! thanks a lot! Good explanation aswell.

Comment: What I also need to point out that double quotation marks around the regex would have me double backslashes. That is why I am using `'` (apostrophes).

Comment: I have an additional problem. sometimes there is an extra "-" on the end of the string. I want to remove this so I thought I capture "-" in a group (if it is in the middle) and then remove the ones on the end. Of course there will be a way better solution, but I could only think of this. The problem however is that it places an space where I don't want one. https://regex101.com/r/eM7mB5/3 Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps, [this](https://regex101.com/r/eM7mB5/4). `$re = '/\b([WL])(2[5-9]|3[0-9]|4[0-4])\b(?:[-]$)?/m'; ` --> `$2$1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Took me some time to understand but I didn't see the /gm on the end.

Comment: If you do not want to depend on `/m`, use `(?:[-](?:\n|$))?` (match a newline or end of string).